# Font import doesn't apply to Arabic text

Tags: html, css, font-family, google-webfonts, google-fonts

I am trying to import a Google font 'Almarai' to my HTML code but it doesn't work. I tried both link and import methods:

Link method:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS method:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap');
```

Body CSS method:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap');

body{
  background: $(body.background);
  background-color: $(body.background.color);
  font-family: 'Almarai', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: $(body.text.color);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

It works but not with Arabic text.I can't keep the default font for Arabic text because it doesn't look good at all.

Comment: Your import code looks great! Maybe the problem comes from somewhere else...On which environment do you work? What is this syntax $(body.background)?

Comment: This is non-reproducible. It works fine for me.

Comment: I am using Blogger blogspot

Answer (score 0):

can you try bu adding this link

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&family=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

css rule

```
font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;

font-family: 'Almarai', sans-serif;
```

here is the google font]link

[https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Almarai?preview.text_type=custom&selection.family=Akaya+Telivigala|Almarai:wght@300&query=Almarai&sidebar.open=true](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Almarai?preview.text_type=custom&selection.family=Akaya+Telivigala%7CAlmarai:wght@300&query=Almarai&sidebar.open=true)

is it not worked  change & to &amp in the link

Comment: When I use the <link> method in head section I get this error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 77; The reference to entity "family" must end with the ';' delimiter.
I tried import and css rules that you suggested but the font refuse to change

Comment: You need to escape the ampersand & to &amp. Can you try this by changing & to &amp in link

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 81; The reference to entity "ampdisplay" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: Is the link above that I need to add in head section or the link given by google fonts?

Comment: uou should add   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&ampfamily=Almarai:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">